# C++: regex matching code, printing multiple matches?

Tags: c++, regex

I'm using the following code which is similar to Stroustrup's C++ 4th Edition Page 127&128.  Per output log below, it prints the first match, however not the match for the trailing -XXXX digits.

Does anyone know why the trailing digits are not matched and/or printed??

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ZIP code pattern: XXddddd-dddd and variants
    regex pat (R"(\w{2}\s*\d{5}(−\d{4})?)");
    int lineno = 0;

    for (string line; getline(cin,line);) {
    ++lineno;
    smatch matches; // matched strings go here
    if (regex_search(line, matches, pat)) // search for pat in line
        for (auto p : matches) {
            cout << p << " ";
        }
    cout << endl;
//      cout << lineno << ": " << matches[0] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output log:

```
$ ./a.out
AB00000-0000
AB00000
```

Comment: how many matches per single regex_search ?

Comment: try `cout << matches[0] << "," << matches[1] << "," << matches[2] << "," ;` really is a single match, _matches_ is misnomer

Comment: `−` is not `-`. That are two different symbols. You have `−` in the code and `-` in the input.

Comment: what you see is second line match, but since `( − \d{4} )?` is option, it not matched, probly not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`−` is not `-`. That are two different symbols. You have `−` in the code and `-` in the input. Here I fixed the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ZIP code pattern: XXddddd-dddd and variants
    regex pat (R"(\w{2}\s*\d{5}(-\d{4})?)");
    int lineno = 0;

    for (string line; getline(cin,line);) {
    ++lineno;
    smatch matches; // matched strings go here
    if (regex_search(line, matches, pat)) // search for pat in line
        for (auto p : matches) {
            cout << p << " ";
        }
    cout << endl;
//      cout << lineno << ": " << matches[0] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```